# Inverse square root intrinsics

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Are there compiler intrinsics for the inverse square root, single and double-precision floating-point, on a scalar argument ?

I can find these for packed SIMD arguments (SSE and AVX) but not for scalars.

Anything faster than division by the `<math.h>` square-root is welcome as well.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800815/fast-inverse-square-root-trick

Comment: @Damien: I am afraid this doesn't beat the built-in functions in terms of time and accuracy.

Comment: I am surprised, but as you did the test... I also found this post for `double`, but I guess it will provide similar performances: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644441/fast-inverse-square-root-on-x64

Comment: rsqrtss (or _mm_rsqrt_ss as an intrinsic). As always [intel Intrinsics Guide is your friend](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=rsqrt&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2). Cant see one for double but just use the packed one and extract the result.

Comment: @MikeVine: yep, I know these.

Comment: The intrinsic itself isn't the issue. It's knowing about _mm_set_ss and _mm_cvtss_f32. Without those, getting intrinsics to generate the equivalent code for standard float/double C++ is impossible. Infact, there are cases where standard C++ will always be faster than the intrinsic equivalent (basically this happens when you have to use a _ps variant, because no _ss variant exists)

Answer (score 4):

Here you go....

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>

// identical to std::sqrt
inline float sqrt(const float f)
{
    __m128 temp = _mm_set_ss(f);
    temp = _mm_sqrt_ss(temp);
    return _mm_cvtss_f32(temp);
}

// faster than  1.0f/std::sqrt, but with little accuracy.
inline float rsqrt(const float f)
{
    __m128 temp = _mm_set_ss(f);
    temp = _mm_rsqrt_ss(temp);
    return _mm_cvtss_f32(temp);
}

// identical to std::sqrt
inline double sqrt(const double f)
{
    __m128d temp = _mm_set_sd(f);
    temp = _mm_sqrt_sd(temp, temp);
    return _mm_cvtsd_f64(temp);
}

// identical to 1.0 / std::sqrt
// .... there isn't an instruction for rsqrt with double, 
// so 1.0 / std::sqrt is the best you've got. 
inline double rsqrt(const double f)
{
    __m128d temp = _mm_set_sd(f);
    temp = _mm_div_sd(_mm_set_sd(1.0), _mm_sqrt_sd(temp, temp));
    return _mm_cvtsd_f64(temp);
}
```

Comparison against std::sqrt(): https://godbolt.org/z/uufv3W

If you enable -ffast-math (or float precision fast, in MSVC) then std::sqrt is likely to generate the same code as using the intrinsics anyway. The only exception is rsqrt for float (clang will convert 1/sqrt to an rsqrt + newton-raphson iteration).

Obviously rsqrt comes with some very nasty floating error. It may be ok for say, normalising a bunch of surface normals for OpenGL rendering, but for almost everything else, the lack of accuracy makes it mostly useless. *(e.g. the quadratic formula)*

Any 'Quake3 optimised rsqrt' nonsense you see around, will be many orders of magnitude slower than calling std::sqrt directly, but with terrible accuracy.

At least once a month or so, when working in the games industry, some new guy would try to 'optimise' the code by replacing std::sqrt with it. *sigh*

**TL;DR: If you have fast math enabled, just use std::sqrt. If fast-math is disabled, then the C++ standard dictates error codes to be set for errno, which will force the compiler to use the std library version.**

Comment: I just checked, out of curiosity, on several computers:

 * 1.0f / sqrtf(x) reference speed 1.0.
 * Quake: ~0.5.
 * Intrinsic: ~0.25.

So perhaps, the Quake version may be passing away.

I can't check it with ARM at the moment. But I have only found the vrsqrte_f32 instruction for 2 floats. I think there is no version for a single value.

Comment: I don't believe your results (I suspect your profiling methodology to be flawed). Do you have fast-math enabled? Are you doing something silly like benchmarking a for loop that rsqrts elements in an array? (i.e you're memory bandwidth limited). Are you utilising the results of the sqrt? (i.e. is the compiler failing to generate code for your test). Are you doing this in release?

Comment: How rude! Post your own results here if you think they're going to be that different from mine. The quake version is around two times faster than 1/sqrt, and the intrinsics version is four times faster, on my computer. Is it not enough for you?